# Unnecessary downvote and subsequent deletion based on unlikely SO link rot

Tags: discussion

So an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2693314/295783) was downvoted and deleted with this comment

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. –  Søren Holten Hansen

However the link was to an upvoted answer at SO and likely given when I did not have enough rep to mark as duplicate.

Question: [DNN: Registered Mark changing to Question Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693170/dnn-registered-mark-changing-to-question-mark/2693314?noredirect=1#comment35960113_2693314)

My Link: [Question mark characters displaying within text, why is this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241015/question-mark-characters-displaying-within-text-why-is-this)

I believe it is not good practice to copy content from an SO answer into another SO answer but instead link to it. Have these rules changed again?

Comment: I was confused by your 'link was internal' when I realized you mean that it is a link to a question/answer on SO....

Comment: That link would have been better placed in a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 8):

This keeps coming up, but if you can post an identical answer to a question then it's a good indication that the question is a duplicate. As such it should be closed. If you don't have the reputation to vote then flag. The question will then be reviewed by others.

If the question isn't a duplicate then the answer should be tailored to fit the new question, and posted as a complete answer to the new question.

As an aside this is a prime example of why link only answers are bad answers. If the target of the link goes away the answer becomes useless.

Comment: An upvoted answer at SO is unlikely to disappear. So you are not actually answering my question

Comment: @mplungjan - not necessarily. If the question it's attached to gets deleted no amount of up-votes are going to save the answer.

Comment: 'K - then I have been misinformed about posting code from other answers instead of a link to the answer

Comment: @mplungjan - As I said in the answer, if you can post code from another answer then it's a very strong sign the question is a duplicate. You should be voting to close, not answering.

Comment: It was not a true duplicate as it turned out, but the link to the answer which is longer than I care to copypaste was still a good link